# Resolving relative paths outside the standard directories (applicationDirectory, desktopDirectory, etc)

Tags: air, filesystems

I need to navigate to a file relative to my applicationDirectory, but as it says in the documentation:

*No ".." reference that reaches the file system root or the application-persistent storage root passes that node; it is ignored.*

But the crazy thing is that if I do something like

```
File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("/home/myHome/");
```

I can get anywhere in the filesystem.

My question is: 
is there a workaround to navigate from my applicationDirectory to a relative path like "../../my.cfg" ?? (I need to read a config file generated by a different application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are trying to access root privileged folders - than you can not.

in other cases try do next "home/blah/blah/blah/../../my.cfg" and research once again http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/jslr/flash/filesystem/File.html to save your time about navigation.

also you have another few ways: create a link to your file or run external bash/bat script.

Comment: as I said, my application is placed inside a subfolder of another application, so in order to load the main config file I would need to go up one folder with a "../../". But AIR is limited in that (can't go up further than the main AIR app), so I either use an absolute path (like /home/myHome) or otherwise I'd need to find a workaround. I can't create a link, and I don't know how using a bash could help me. Thank you anyways! it's always good to read others' opinions!

Comment: i was mean, some another construction like: **getApplicationPath()+"../../"+url2file**

Comment: wow, I'm shocked by the solution of the workaround, why did they even put that limitation?! I did something like    var baseDir:File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("."); and it gave me the current path. Then I did     var newPath:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(baseDir.nativePath+"/../../"); and it magically went up, ignoring the thing written in the documentation. Blah. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was previously using the little hack mentioned in Eugene's answer to copy from an absolute path:

```
var file = 'C:\Users\User1\Pictures\pic.png';
var newPath = air.File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('images/pic.png');

air.File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('/../../../../../../../../../../' +
  file).copyTo(newPath, true);
```

However, this is a *much* better way of doing it:

```
var file = 'C:\Users\User1\Pictures\pic.png';
var newPath = air.File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('images/pic.png');

new air.File(file).copyTo(newPath, true);
```